# Allow users to edit their post while an image is being uploaded, instead of forcing them to wait until the image is fully uploaded

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Since [image uploads are slow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350284/178179), it would be convenient to allow users to edit their post while uploading an image. I.e. do the upload + image processing in the background.

Currently one has to wait until the image is included in the post before being able to edit the post:

[image]

Comment: One man's irritation is another man's marvel at how quick and easy it is to upload images.

Comment: I know Ive seen this before

Comment: @Mari-LouA No irritation, just trying to save some human time.

Comment: five seconds...wow. How many seconds do you spend composing any post? Is it less than a minute?

Comment: @Mari-LouA waiting for the image upload is waste of human time, unlike writing a post.

Comment: Response times of computer systems *are* very important. Why aren't computer systems' response times now practically zero when computers are now literally at least 1,000 times faster? (Perl scripts certainly runs *much* faster now than under [MacPerl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/macperl/) on early 1990s Macs.)